# How Do I Extract a Full Icon From a Vista/7 Executable?

Tags: c#, .net, icons, windows-vista, extract

If I have a Vista .ico file which contains a 16x16, 32x32, 256x256 etc. version of an icon, I can successfully load it as a .NET Icon by simply doing -:

```
Icon myIcon = new Icon("C:\\MyIcon.ico");
```

I can then access all of the various sized images in the icon.  I can even access the 256x256 Vista PNG using methods detailed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220465/using-256-x-256-vista-icon-in-application/1945764#1945764).

However, I haven't found a way to get the full set of icon images from a Vista executable.  Unfortunately, doing this -:

```
Icon myIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\\MyExe.exe");
```

...only results in a single 32x32 image being extracted.  Is there a way get the entire set of images from an executable as a .NET Icon?  Preferably one that also works in XP.

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet with PrivateExtractIcons API:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      internal static extern UInt32 PrivateExtractIcons(String lpszFile, int nIconIndex, int cxIcon, int cyIcon, IntPtr[] phicon, IntPtr[] piconid, UInt32 nIcons, UInt32 flags);

IntPtr[] phicon = new IntPtr[] { IntPtr.Zero };
IntPtr[] piconid = new IntPtr[] { IntPtr.Zero };

PrivateExtractIcons(path, 0, cx, cy, phicon, piconid, 1, 0);

if (phicon[0] != IntPtr.Zero)
    return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(phicon[0]);
```