# Convert picture to icon with Visual Basic NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**Visual Basic NET**

Hello, I have coded a programme which save the icon of a *.exe file into a picture, and now the question, how can I convert the picture to a real icon file?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

sounds very much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173736/how-do-i-extract-a-full-icon-from-a-vista-7-executable), which links to this [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconExtractor.aspx) article.

A picutre is not an icon but could represent one frame of an icon so, I think that step is erroneous.