# How do I get TKageyu.Utils to work in my project? (for extracting 256pixels icons)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a small app in C# (.net 4.0, VS 2012), and as part of it I need to extract an icon of another EXE file.
I found that I can use ExtractVistaIcon in a combination with TKageyu.Utils.
The problem is, there is no such thing TKageyu.Utils as what VS.net 2012 says.

```
using TKageyu.Utils;
```

Results with:

> "The type or namespace name 'TKageyu' could not be found"

What should I do? Where can I get it?

---

The code I'm trying to use it with:

```
using (TKageyu.Utils.IconExtractor IconEx = new TKageyu.Utils.IconExtractor(fullPath))
{
      Icon icoAppIcon = IconEx.GetIcon(0); // Because standard System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon() returns ONLY 32x32.
      picboxAppLogo.Image = ExtractVistaIcon(icoAppIcon);
}
```

Original code taken from:
[Using 256 x 256 Vista icon in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220465/using-256-x-256-vista-icon-in-application)
(Will be edited by me when I get it to work)

Comment: I guess you need to add a reference to the assembly you want to use.

Comment: You need to download the [source for the TKageyu icon extractor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26824/Extract-icons-from-EXE-or-DLL-files), build it, and reference the DLL from your project. You could also copy the classes from that project into your project if you want.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I don't know which assembly this is...

Comment: @Simon McKenzie - how do I do add a reference DLL to a project?

Comment: @Simon McKenzie Never Mind - I just took the whole namespace into the app and it works!! (took a little bit of adjustments though)

Comment: @TDT-Alpha - for future reference (you'll definitely come across this stuff again), right-click on your project, select "Add Reference", then browse to the DLL.

Comment: @Simon McKenzie - I just don't know how to make a dll from another project...

Comment: @TDT-Alpha, if you have the other project in Visual Studio, just build it. You'll find the DLL in the project folder, under `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`

Comment: @Simon McKenzie - It results in EXE, that the 'problem'...

Comment: @TDT-Alpha, this should be my last post (hopefully) - otherwise we'll have to move this to chat. Just open the TKageyu project's "Project Properties" and change the "Output Type" from "Windows Application" to "Class Library". Your existing solution is probably the best approach, but in the future, this may be useful to you. Cheers, Simon

Comment: @Simon McKenzie - THANKS man!!! it is the last message... I already want to check the answer but I can only tomorrow... (now I have other problems - but I have no energy left..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Simon McKenzie I found this way to solve my problem:

1. Go to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26824/Extract-icons-from-EXE-or-DLL-files
   Download the app
2. Open the SLN file in Visual Studio (I did in 2012)
3. Open Form1.cs, copy the namespace there and the includes (just to make sure..)
4. Go to your project and paste the namespace in the file you need it,
   Also check that you have all the includes that the namespace needed in the other file.
5. USE IT! :)

I used it like so:

```
using (TKageyu.Utils.IconExtractor IconEx = new TKageyu.Utils.IconExtractor(fullPath))
        {
            Icon icoAppIcon = IconEx.GetIcon(0); // Because standard System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon() returns ONLY 32x32.
            Bitmap hBitmap = ExtractVistaIcon(icoAppIcon);
            IntPtr hLBitmap = hBitmap.GetHbitmap();
            ImageSource wBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hLBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            IconBox_1.Source = wBitmap;
            IconBox_S.Source = wBitmap;
            IconBox_C.Source = wBitmap;
            IconBox_W.Source = wBitmap;
        }
```